# Assigning Knowledge Articles to a queue in apex

Tags: apex, knowledge, translation

I'm trying to use the [`KbManagement.PublishingService`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm#apex_KbManagement_PublishingService_methods) class to assign a `KnowledgeArticleVersion` back to a queue after it was programmatically updated after creation and got assigned to the the current user.

```
KbManagement.PublishingService.assignDraftTranslationTask(
    /*articleVersionId*/ kavId,
    /*assigneeId*/ queueId,
    /*instructions*/ '',
    /*dueDate*/ null,
    /*sendEmailNotification*/ false
);
```

However, everything I've tried gives this error:

> System.InvalidParameterValueException: You have selected an invalid assignee.

Even when I get the `AssignedToId` from an article that was assigned through the salesforce UI, and that ID matches the `groupId` of the queue, it still won't work.

What am I missing here? Can this method only assign ownership to a user or something? And if so, how do you assign it back to a queue?

---

**Update**: I've got an answer back from SalesForce, that this is just not possible as it stands now. So you can assign to users, cannot assign to queues.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like you're sure this Queue is already configured to allow ownership of the proper objects?

Comment: Yes, it's a localization queue where articles are automatically assigned to, but since I edit the article in code after it's created, it gets then assigned to the user that triggered it. I need to get it back to be "free for all" in the queue.

Comment: Are you trying to reassign the article or a draft translation task?

Comment: The translation draft articleVersion of the article. The method takes that Id as the first parameter. I'm not sure what else I would pass to it?

Comment: Just to add, I've confirmed that I can assign the task to users directly with this method, just not to a queue. Also, I can assign that article translation to the queue using the salesforce ui.
In the browser, I looked at the POST when assigning and it's using the 15 digit ID of the queue, instead of the 18 digit one, but neither works for this method call to the publishing service.